# Why does the memory of this C code get corrupted?

Tags: c

A few days ago, I was trying to make a little password generator in C so that I can generate passwords of any length and with any special set of characters that I need (like for example, only capital letters or only small letters). I wanted to do it as a fun little project but I encountered something weird with my code that I wrote. Here's the code:

```
#include "str2int.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CAPITALS "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
#define SMALL "abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz"
#define ALPHABET "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz"
#define NUMBERS "1234567890"
#define SPECIALS "!#$@&"
#define ALLCHARS "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz1234567890!#$@&"

int passlength, errcode;
char* characters;
int numinclude = 0, specialinclude = 0, alphainclude = 0, capitalinclude = 0, smallinclude = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    if (argc > 1) {
        passlength = str2int(argv[1]);
        errcode = errorCheck();
        if (errcode != 0) {
            printf("passgen %s\n", argv[1]);
            printf("        ^ Here\n");
            printf("Invalid input for integer");
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        printf("Usage: passgen <passlength> [add-all] [include-numbers] [include-specials] [include-alphabet] [include-capitals] [include-small]");
        printf("\n[] = Optional, <> = Required\n");
        printf("Options:\n");
        printf("    add-all: Includes all characters. Default option if no flags are provided.\n");
        printf("    include-numbers: Adds numbers to the list of usable characters.\n");
        printf("    include-specials: Adds special characters (!#$@&) to the list of usable characters.\n");
        printf("    include-alphabet: Adds the entire alphabet (including capital and small letters) to the list of usable characters.\n");
        printf("    include-capitals: Adds the capital alphabet to the list of usable characters.\n");
        printf("    include-small: Adds the small alphabet to the list of usable characters.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "add-all") == 0) {
                characters = (char*) realloc(characters, 68);
                strcat(characters, ALLCHARS);
                break;
            }
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "include-numbers") == 0) {
                if (numinclude == 0) {
                    characters = (char*) realloc(characters, 11);
                    strcat(characters, NUMBERS);
                    numinclude = 1;
                }
            }
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "include-specials") == 0) {
                if (specialinclude == 0) {
                    characters = (char*) realloc(characters, 6);
                    strcat(characters, SPECIALS);
                    specialinclude = 1;
                }
            }
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "include-alphabet") == 0) {
                if (alphainclude == 0) {
                    characters = (char*) realloc(characters, 53);
                    strcat(characters, ALPHABET);
                    alphainclude = 1;
                    capitalinclude = 1;
                    smallinclude = 1;
                }
            }
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "include-capitals") == 0) {
                if (capitalinclude == 0) {
                    characters = (char*) realloc(characters, 27);
                    strcat(characters, CAPITALS);
                    capitalinclude = 1;
                    if (capitalinclude && smallinclude) {
                        alphainclude = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (strcmp(argv[i], "include-small") == 0) {
                if (smallinclude == 0) {
                    characters = (char*) realloc(characters, 27);
                    strcat(characters, SMALL);
                    smallinclude = 1;
                    if (smallinclude && capitalinclude) {
                        alphainclude = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        goto generate;
    }
    characters = (char*) realloc(characters, 68);
    characters = ALLCHARS;
    generate:
    printf("Generating password with length %d\n", passlength);
    for (int x = 0; x < passlength; x++){
        printf("%c", characters[rand() % ((int) strlen(characters))]);
    }
}
```

It's a lot, but it basically just checks if you input something like 'include-numbers', and adds a list of numbers (defined at the top) to a character pointer named 'characters'. And I do that for basically every option, and for the most part I think all of that code works as intended. My only issue is, that when I go to test it it prints out something that shouldn't be printed out.
For example, if I write in the console:

```
passgen 10
```

It generates a string of 10 letters back with all of the characters I defined at the top (#define ALLCHARS).
That works fine, but if I try to do:

```
passgen 10 include-numbers
```

It should print out a string of 10 numbers from the NUMBERS macro I defined, but instead I get:

```
9l724`è470
```

What I think this is, is that the rand() function (which should be selecting a random address limited by the % strlen(characters) thing), is actually trying to access memory outside the stuff I allocated to characters in the for loop, even though it should've been practically filling all of the allocated memory, and only picking stuff in that list. I'm quite new to C, so I'm quite new to the mindset of working with memory addresses and stuff, and I basically have no idea why this isn't working as intended.
Also, sorry I couldn't come up with a good title, I have no idea what this issue even is and I think it probably could be some kind of memory corruption? Also I'm extremely new to StackOverflow, so I'm sorry if this question is a little dumb or easy to answer, but I honestly have no clue what to do.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting that `realloc()` extends an allocation by `X` bytes, when it actually resizes it (grows or reduces) to `X` bytes.

Comment: What is `str2int`? Post a [mcve] (and don't ignore the "minimal" part).

Comment: Aside, you can use previous definitions to create another, e.g. `#define ALPHABET CAPITALS SMALL` etc.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, i thought OP meant arguments `passgen 10` :-) My bad ...

Comment: str2int is a library I made for converting a string to Int, with error checking and stuff. Sorry for not clarifying that @EugeneSh.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've never known you could actually do that in C. That's pretty cool!

Comment: Strings literals concatenate automatically, for example `printf("%s\n", "AB" "CD");`.

Comment: @sj95126 Is there any way for me to extend an allocated section of memory? Or at least to get the size of the characters pointer in size_t so that I can add extra size to it and realloc() with that size?

Comment: @SummerNugget: You'll have to keep a count of how many bytes you've previously allocated, increase it by some amount, and then pass that to `realloc()`.

Comment: I tried to do something like `characters = (char*) realloc(characters, bytes + 68); bytes += 68` to keep track of the number of bytes but it hasn't worked too well, and I don't think it actually helped much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (or at least one of them) is that you are calling `strcat` with a non null terminated `char` array in all the cases:

```
characters = (char*) realloc(characters, 6);
strcat(characters, SPECIALS);
```

Comment: So how do I fix it though? Do I just add a null byte at the end of it?

Comment: Not at the end but at the beginning: `characters[0] = '\0';` or use `strcpy` that doesn't require a null terminated array, or better yet, use `snprintf` which is the safe version of `strcpy`.

Comment: I can't exactly use strcpy, unless that concatenates strings because the `characters` pointer is supposed to be something I can use as something to generate a random string from

Comment: Ah, ok, now I see, you can use more that one encoding isn't it? i.e. `include-number include-specials`, then you are misusing `realloc`, you need a variable that stores the space necessary to relocate the old data plus the new data, and yes, in this case you null terminate the char array in the first iteration with `characters[0] = '\0';`

Comment: I've just tried to use the strcpy() method and it ABSOLUTELY WORKS!! The only issue left to fix is that if I run the executable with `passgen 10 include-numbers include-alphabet` it only gives back a password with the alphabet but I'll do some more testing (because of course something like 52 characters is wayyy more than 10 characters so I'll try and see if it works with something like only specials and numbers)

Comment: Yes, see the comment above yours.

Comment: Also I've added a 'byte' int variable that tracks the number of bytes that have been allocated, and I just do bytes + (some number) to extend it, and then add that same number to the variable to keep track

Comment: can you also show me an example of `realloc()` fix? Because I have no idea how to implement that in code.

Comment: @SummerNugget https://ideone.com/M112mn

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It is really well optimized, and I love it! Only issue, though, is that if I don't provide anything at all it absolutely breaks the output like before and gives me a bunch of unicode text for some reason.

Comment: Found the issue with it. The array `characters` in your code is never going to be NULL, as you allocate memory to it. That results in the code accessing the allocated, but very much uninitialized memory, and then trying to convert that into text. So I fixed that and it works now!

Comment: Notice that It's a good exercise for learning dynamic memory, but in those cases where you have a short maximum length, you can avoid using `realloc` and use static memory, something like `char characters[1024];`

Comment: I have tried that, but I wasn't sure if `strlen()` would actually return me the string length in `characters` or if it would just return me the size of the array itself. Either way, thanks for the code and I appreciate the help!

Comment: `strlen` works with both approaches, it only wants a null terminated char array (a c string). You are welcome :)